# Lotus notes: Invalid Internet address specified after mail send

Tags: lotus-notes

i have a problem to send mail using notes 6.5.6
i have 2 user (user1 and user2):

When i try to send an email form user1 all work and the email is correctly sent

When i try to send an email form user2 lotus notes retrive me :
"Error transferring to (server ip); Invalid Internet address specified. Invalid Internet address specified."

So have compared the two location file of the users that but i didn't find any difference;
I compared the two .id fiel but there's no differrence so i don't understand what's the problem.

in despair i try to copy and past the location doc of user1 and replace the mail and .id references with those of user2 but notes retrive the same error message.

there's anybody can help me ?
thank's

Comment: From all users the "trace" command to the mail server work well

Comment: Did You change the Internet- Address- Field in the location document (first Tab)?
Does User2 have a valid internet address set in his person document on the server?

Does the error come from your server or the client?
Do you send the mails directly to the internet with the client, or do ou use the server?

Comment: The internet address is the same for all user (general company address) and it's the same in all location doc. the error come from a client but in the same client but diffent user email work well. i don't know if i send email directly to internet... i send mail to  @gmail.com address

Comment: You use the same email address for every users? This is NOT a supported configuration. Mail addresses have to be unique in the company. That's why your configuration does not work. Of course you could teach the server to "ignore" this by setting the notes.ini- variable RouterTranslateSpecial=0 on the server. see this link: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21089673

Comment: But i use set the same internet mail address in the location doc and  the same internet .id file of all users in other company and it work... and they haven't RouterTranslateSpecial configured...

Comment: Sorry, I went the wrong direction: This message is not about senders' mailaddress but about the recipient. Then something is wrong with the addressing. Either the location has the wrong Directory Server or the location might be set to send the mail directly to the internet.

Comment: In the location doc send outgoing mail is set to throught domino server

Comment: and the directory server?

Comment: is null, what i have to write ? also in the other company is null

Comment: Without seeing your complete config, I run out of ideas. Sorry

Comment: I HAVE RESOLVED ! I replaced (in the location doc) the "domino mail domain" and the "home mail server" with the ip of the server il place of the name of it and now all users are able to send email ! it was as if the server name can not be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I HAVE RESOLVED ! I replaced (in the location doc) the "domino mail domain" and the "home mail server" with the ip of the server il place of the name of it and now all users are able to send email ! it was as if the server name can not be resolved.

Comment: Then a conenction document for user1 had been created on installation. Just change it to be available for all users, then you can change that back to the mailserver... Ip Addresses in location documents can cause multiople issues